# Making CE function of calculator in javascript

Tags: javascript

In javascript i'm trying to make a calculator only i have problems with making a CE function that clears everthing after the operator in this case the number 88.909 needs to be delete and the operator in this case the "*" and everthing for that needs to stil be there and not get delete.

the to functions are two atempts at making and both clear the whole string

```
var string = "55.6*88.909";

function test() {
    do{
        string = string.substr(0,string.length-1);
        console.log(string);
    }while (string.length-1 !== "*" || string.length-1 !== "+" || string.length-1 !== "-" || string.length-1 !== "/");
}

function test2() {
    for(let i = 0; string.length-i != "*" || string.length-i != "+"; i++ ){
        string = string.substr(0,string.length-1);
        console.log(string);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the CE function? & What operator clears the calculator screen?

Comment: What is this code?!

Comment: first I'm trying out things to make a CE function after that is goes on a button in html

Comment: We can appreciate that you're stuck on something, but "I have problems" isn't really an answerable question.  Which function are you asking about?  What specific result do you expect from that function?  What specific result do you currently observe?  Have you used your browser's debugging tools at all?

Comment: Please describe your problem more specially, do not hesitate to write more details about your problem

Comment: everything that comes after the operator goes away in this the '*'

Comment: @KeesvanOpdorp: I'm afraid that doesn't clarify what you're asking *at all*.  Please take some time and edit the question to specifically describe the problem.

Comment: @David is it now clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would want something like this:

```
function test2() {
  let i = 0;
  let firstNumber;
  let secondNumber;
  let operator;

  while (string[i] !== '*' && string[i] !== '+') {
    i++;
  }

  firstNumber = string.substr(0, i);
  secondNumber = string.substr(i + 1);
  operator = string[i];

  console.log(firstNumber);
  console.log(operator);
  console.log(secondNumber);
}
```

Comment: I go trying this code I think it is the & & that makes the difference

Comment: You have an infinite loop because you are checking for the string.length inside your for loop's condition which is never changed.